# DistinguishedName attribute of Active Directory

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, active-directory

This is my code :

```
public bool ActiveDirectoryAuthenticate(string username, string password)
{
   var result = false;

   using (var entry = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://*****/DC=******,DC=biz",username,password,AuthenticationTypes.Secure))
   {
       var searcher = new DirectorySearcher(entry){Filter = "objectClass=user"};

       try
       {
           var sr = searcher.FindOne();
           var PathDic = sr.Properties["distinguishedName"][0].ToString();
           result = true;
       }
       catch (Exception exception)
       {
       }
    }

    return result;
}
```

The problem is

```
sr.Properties["distinguishedName"][0].ToString();
```

does not return correct value.

Please help me

Comment: What **does it** return? And what is the **correct** value??

Comment: it only returns server name and domain name but i want to return the directories which i made

Comment: Can you please **SHOW US** an example and explain what you expected/wanted? I still don't understand what your issue really is ...

Comment: correct : CN=BANK.Members,OU=MBank,OU=Development,OU=Technical,OU=pt,DC=pt,
DC=biz
incorrect:
CN=Administrator,CN=Users,DC=pt,DC=biz

Answer (score 0):

Just an idea but don't you need to put *value* like this :

```
var PathDic = sr.Properties["distinguishedName"][0].Value.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

My problem resolve:

```
public bool ActiveDirectoryAuthenticate(string username, string password)
    {
        var result = false;
        using (
            var entry = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://PT/DC=pt,DC=biz", username, password,
                AuthenticationTypes.Secure))
        {
            var searcher = new DirectorySearcher(entry) {Filter = "sAMAccountName=Bank.Members"};

            searcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("distinguishedName");
            try
            {
                var sr = searcher.FindOne();
                var name = sr.Properties["distinguishedName"][0].ToString();
                result = true;
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {


            }
        }

        return result;
    }
```